# Loading Local WSDL For Remote Webservice

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

The organization I'm trying to connect to has asked if I could load their WSDL from a local resource before executing their functions. I've tried a bunch of options but I keep getting could not connect to host errors. Here's my logic

```
 $sc = new SoapClient("http://localhost.com/wsdl.xml", array());
```

I've also tried:

```
 $sc = new SoapClient("http://localhost.com/wsdl.xml, array ( "encoding"=>"ISO-8859-1",
        "stream_context" => stream_context_create($opts),
        "trace"=>1,
        "location"=>'http://remoteurl.com/wsdl',
        "exceptions"=>TRUE,
        "connection_timeout"=>20000 ));
```

If I just use the remoteurl.com/wsdl it works. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just save the complete wsdl-file including the referenced xsd (if used) to local drive (or network share) and change the url-path prefix from 'http://...' to 'file://..local-wsdl-path-here'